# Z3: iz3proof_itp::proof_error and iz3translation::unsupported error when using bitvectors

Tags: z3

I am using the inbuilt interpolation feature on the latest (unstable branch) version of Z3. It works fine with SMT2 formulas containing integers. It does however, throw a `iz3proof_itp::proof_error` and a subsequent `iz3translate::unsupported error` (See Below) for the following SMT2 program -

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic QF_AUFBV)
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun b () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun x1 () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun x2 () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun x3 () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun y1 () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun y2 () (_ BitVec 32))
(compute-interpolant
 (= a (_ bv0 32))
 (= b (bvneg (_ bv2 32)))
 (= x1 (_ bv1 32))
 (= y1 (_ bv0 32))
 (= x2 (bvadd x1 a))
 (= x3 (bvadd x2 b))
 (= y2 (bvadd y1 a))
 (bvsge x3 (_ bv0 32))
)
```

I tried it on the online version on rise4fun, and it worked fine. So after a bit of debugging, I found that the error is thrown from inside the function `find_congruence_position` in file `iz3proof_itp.cpp`.

So I made the following simple (maybe dangerous) change to the function to take care of the proof_error atleast for now -

Changing `if(x == arg(arg(con,0),i) && (y == arg(arg(con,1),i))` at line 2431

to `if((x == arg(arg(con,0),i) && (y == arg(arg(con,1),i))) || (y == arg(arg(con,0),i) && (x == arg(arg(con,1),i))))`

I simply or'd the condition with its copy where x and y are interchanged - I had found that x and y sometimes have their values interchanged, maybe due to some proof techniques.

This did take care of the problem, I found that using equality and non-equality, along with bvadd or bvneg with BitVecs while computing interpolants worked. For example the following file worked -

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic QF_AUFBV)
(declare-fun a () (_ BitVec 32))
(declare-fun b () (_ BitVec 32))
(compute-interpolant
 (= a (_ bv0 32))
 (= b (bvadd a (_ bv1 32)))
 (= b (_ bv0 32))
)
```

But then I tried using relational operators, like bvsgt or bvsge, and it threw a new error -

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'iz3translation::unsupported'`

I looked more into it, found out that the expression causing the problem was -

`(not ((_ bit2bool 2) x2))` - it was assigned a PR_TH_LEMMA type and the UNKNOWN_THEORY kind. It seems that there is no support for such operations.

Since the online version is working, I'd like to know if it's possible to obtain that version. I read the previous questions and answers on StackOverflow, and I'm a bit confused. Some say BitVec theory is not supported (Although these posts are old), but then how is the online version working? Or am I doing something wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, interpolation for bit vector arithmetic is not supported. It's interesting that it works on the web version. That version is quite old, however, and I think it predates the source-available version of Z3. I can think of two possible reasons why it works:

1) That version of interpolating Z3 used the "foci" prover as a backup. Whenever it encountered a part of the proof it didn't understand, it would package that part up as a lemma and reprove it using foci. The current version does not use foci (which is a third-party tool not available in source) and relies entirely on the proof generated by Z3.

2) The older version might have been doing bit-blasting in a different way. If all the non-local proof steps are purely propositional (using just the resolution rule) then it is easy to compute an interpolant.

As far as I understand it, however, computing interpolants from an *efficient* bit-vector solver (using all the known pre-processing tricks) is an open problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree with you, it seems to be the most probable reason. An interesting thing however happened, when I passed the above file in an incremental manner (Give the terms as assertions, do (check-sat) along the way, and use (get-interpolant <labels> ) instead of (compute-interpolant), it gives a correct answer. Any thoughts on why it is able to generate a proof when assertions are provided incrementally? I'm sorry but I don't have much knowledge about the proof system in Z3